# How do I make my percentage a decimal in my visual?

Tags: powerbi, format

All,

My percentage for EBITA in the query is set for decimal. In my table, it's carrying over as one thousands (i.e.1900.00% vs 19.00%). How do I change this in my table? I'm trying to add it to a visual gauge and want the gauge to show 19%, not 1900%:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6lcg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is this percentage calculated? It looks like there are Numbers in the table like "19" (=1900%), "22" (=2200%) instead of "0.19"(=19%), "0.22"(=22%).

If you have calulcated them, check the formular. If not, the easiest soultion would be calculating a new column and divide the existing one by 100.

Something like:

```
new_col = ['YourTable']EBITDA_Percent__c / 100
```

Comment: Thank you Marco! I thought about that, but thought It could be something in the query. This is helpful and will be what I will use if it happens again! Thank you so much!